# Having threads run from event listeners in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, listener

I have a program that creates hundreds of instances of a class, each of which listens to another thread which simply fires an event on a regular timed schedule (so that they all perform at the same speed).  What I'd like is for each of the hundreds of instances to be its own thread, so that when an event is fired, they can all work in parallel.  What makes sense to me is to have these classes extend the Thread class and then have this code inside them...

```
public class IteratorStepListener implements StepEventListener { 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
           start(); 
      } 
 } 

 public void run() { 
      doStuff();
 }
```

This doesn't seem to work though.  Clearly I'm not understanding something basic here.  What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the event is going to be fired more than once... but you can't start the same thread more than once.

It sounds like your listener should implement the interface but start a thread directly in `actionPerformed` (or better, use an `Executor` so that it could use a thread pool). So instead of your current implementation, you could use:

```
// Assuming the listener implements runnable; you may want to
// delegate that to a separate class for separation of concerns.
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            
    new Thread(this).start(); 
}
```

or

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            
    executor.execute(this);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing.  I was confusing my objects with the threads and no good was coming from it.  I've since added an Executor and everything is running so much more smoothly now.  Thanks everyone who replied, you saved me hours of headache.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, first thing: overcome the notion that your hundreds of threads will run in parallel.  At the very best, they will run *concurrently*, ie, time-sliced.  As you get into the hundreds of threads, you will see the bearings on the scheduling algorithm start to glow; in the thousands they'll smoke and eventually seize up, and you'll get no more threads.

Now, that said, we don't have near enough code to understand what you're really doing, but one thing that I note is you don't seem to be making new Threads.  Remember that a thread is an object; the canonical way to start a thread is

```
  Thread t = new Thread(Runnable r);
  t.run();
```

What it looks like is that you're trying to `run()` the same thread over and over again; this way lies madness.  Have a look at Wiki on [Event Driven Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming).  If you really want to have a separate thread for handling each event, you'll want a scheme something like this (pseudocode):

```
 processEvents: function
     eventQueue: queue of Events
     event: implements Runnable

     -- something produces events and puts them on the queue

     loop -- forever
     do
         Event ev := eventQueue.front
         new Thread(ev).run();
     od
end -- processEvents
```

Comment: *"overcome the notion that your hundreds of threads will run in parallel*" It's not as if it's science-fiction. We have parallel computing, of which some projects are running hundreds of thousands of processors in parallel. We have multi-processor servers, along with the new-ish 100-core processors. And we have supercomputers boasting 10s of thousands of processors. Welcome to the future. (OP may not be targeting such hardware, but let's not spread misinformation.)

Comment: Let me know when you find a JVM that will consume thousands of processors in a highly-parallel machine.

Answer (score 4):

> What I'd like is for each of the hundreds of instances to be its own thread, so that when an event is fired, they can all work in parallel.

I don't think this is a good approach.

- Unless you have hundreds of processors, the threads *cannot possibly* all work in parallel.  You'll end up with the threads running them one at a time (one per processor), or time-slicing between processors.
- Each thread actually ties down a significant slice of the JVM's resources, even when inactive.  IIRC, the default stack size is about 1 Mbyte.
- The example code in your question shows the event calling `start()` on the thread.  Unfortunately, you can only call `start()` on a thread once.  Once the thread has terminated it cannot be restarted.

A better approach would be to create an executor with a bounded thread pool, and have each event cause a new task to be submitted to the executor.  Something like this:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maxPoolSize,
     keepAliveTime, timeUnit, workQueue);

...

public class IteratorStepListener implements StepEventListener, Runnable { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        executor.submit(this);
    }

    public void run() { 
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: the solution allows the same instance to be executed by multiple threads concurrently. Morealso it could cause out-of-order event processing. It's not *hundreds of instances to be its own thread*, I know it might be obvious, just pointing

Answer (score 1):

You can't use threads like that in Java. This is because Java threads directly map to underlying OS threads (at least on JVM implementations that I'm aware of), and OS threads can't scale like that. A rule of thumb is, you want to keep total number of threads within hundred or something in an app. A few hundred is probably ok. A few thousand gets usually problematic, depending on the HW you are using.

The use of threads like you described is a valid implementation strategy in languages like Erlang for example. Meanwhile, if you are stuck with Java this time, creating a shared thread pool and submitting your tasks to this instead of allowing all tasks to run concurrently might be a good alternative. In this case, you can choose a suitable number of threads (best number depends on the nature of the task. If you have no idea, number of CPU core available times 2 is a good start), and have that number of tasks run concurrently.

If you absolutely need all tasks to proceed concurrently, it could get a little complicated, but that's doable as well.